# SVN patch - newer revision; lines content same but different line numbers

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When SVN applies a patch file to a code file, what does it do when one or more of the following are true:

1. The patch revision number is older than the current revision
2. The changes in the patch file occur on a different line than expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I think nothing special will happen except it will increase chances that second part of your question will occur:

> The changes in the patch file occur on a different line than expected

2. As [svnbook says](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.patch.html):

> Changes listed in the patch file will either be applied or rejected.
>   If a change does not match at its exact line offset, it may be applied
>   earlier or later in the file if a match is found elsewhere for the
>   surrounding lines of context provided by the patch. A change may also
>   be applied with fuzz—meaning, one or more lines of context are ignored
>   when attempting to match the change location. If no matching context
>   can be found for a change, the change conflicts and will be written to
>   a reject file which bears the extension .svnpatch.rej.

As a conclusion: you can not really know until you apply your patch and then examine changes made using `right click > Tortoise SVN > Check for modifications` which will open the list of affected files/folders. Right click on them and do either `Compare with base` or `Show changes as unified diff`. Then you will know whether patch has been applied as originally intended.